# Simple theorem from Spivak

Tags: calculus

It’s stated in a lemma in Ch 15 of Spivak that $f’(x)^2 + f(x)^2 = 0$ for all $x$ implies that $f=0$, and I think I should use the fundamental theorem of calculus somehow in that simple proof but I can’t seem to see it. Can anyone provide the short proof or a hint?

Comment: Hint: what happens when you square a number?

Comment: a^2+b^2=0 than a=b=0 since a^2=-b^2 can not hold for any real number except zero

Comment: Thank you to both of you!

Comment: Your function ist real valued, isn't it?

Comment: It's enough to assume $f(x)^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming the function $f$ is real-valued):

Note that, for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $a^2\geq 0$ (hence $-a^2\leq 0$). We can subtract $f’(x)^2$ from both sides of your equality to get the following:
$$0\leq f(x)^2=-f’(x)^2\leq 0\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R},$$
so $f(x)^2=0$ for all $x$, which implies that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, which is what you were asked to prove.